# How to access Stored procedure in Code First Model which return 6 or 7 table combine result

Tags: entity-framework-4

i am new in MVC and entity frame work and i want to create Code first entity frame work.
we have already created project in asp.net and we want to migrate in mvc. we have lots of stored procedure and some procedure return complex data combination of 10 to 12 tables...

As a Proof of Concept we wan't to develop 3 to 4 pages...

i have some question regarding new start.

1) Should i used entity frame work if yes then which is better entity frame work model

- Database first
- Model first
- code first

2) how to integrate stored procedure in Code first model

3) in each page we have minimum 7 to 8 table result there... how i will handle in entity frame work.

this is my first project in mvc and entity framework please help me with appropriated answer.

Answer (score 0):

first, this has nothing to do with MVC. this is purely a data access issue.

second, this is sort of missing the point of using entity framework. if the goal is to migrate away from stored procs that one thing, but to use EF and continue to execute the stored procs defeats the purpose of using a ORM like EF.

Instead for your procs I would stick with raw ADO.Net, or use [Dapper.Net](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) to convert the stored proc result sets into objects.

EF would be a better choice as your convert each proc into EF linq queries. It's not that you can't execute procs (or raw sql) from EF, but it doesn't make much sense. Especially with how you describe the procs.